# Function in Soundex module doesn’t work

Tags: python, spss

This is one of the functions in a soundex module I'm running to deal with SPSS data. It used to work, years ago, but now it generates "Error Computing Case" for each case. Anyone have an idea why this might be happening??

```
def spssoundex(newvariablename,computingvariable):

import spss
varnames = []
varcount = spss.GetVariableCount()
for i in xrange(varcount):
    varnames.append(spss.GetVariableName(i))
varindex = varnames.index(computingvariable)
cursor = spss.Cursor(accessType = 'w')
cursor.SetVarNameAndType([newvariablename],[4])
cursor.CommitDictionary()
for i in range(cursor.GetCaseCount()):
    indcursor = cursor.fetchone()
    try:
        cursor.SetValueChar(newvariablename,get_soundex(indcursor[varindex]))
        cursor.CommitCase()
    except:
        print "Error Computing Case"
        try:
            print casecursor[varnames.index("CASE")]
        except:
            print "CASE variable not in file"
cursor.close
```

Comment: Take out the `try` and the `except` block and see what error you are actually getting. You are trapping all exceptions, which is bad practice because it masks unexpected errors. Modify your `except` to trap only the exception you actually want to handle.

Comment: Instead of doing the cursor to you can probably just use the `SPSSINC TRANS` function.

Answer (score 0):

The extendedTransforms.py module has a soundex function that is easy to use with SPSSINC TRANS. It also has other measures that might work better.  ExtendedTransforms is installed with recent versions of Statistics or it can be obtained from the Community site.  (Small e - drat this iPad).

But tracking down the real error exception might be useful.